# How do I add an search-function to a Table that displays Json-data?

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, filtering, dynamic-tables

My ASP.NET Core project displays data from a Json file as a table on a Razor page.

Now I want to add an search function so it only shows "objects" with the selected userId.

I added an search bar on the razor page but I do not how to use the Searchstring to filter everything that is not selected out.

This is my Razor page that displays the table (ToDoModel.cshtml)

```
@model List<ToDo.Models.ToDoStructure>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ToDoModel";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<form asp-action="ToDoModel" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Find by userId: <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="ToDoModel">Back to Full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<h2>ToDo-List</h2>
@{ 
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>UserId</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Erledigt</th>
        </tr>
    @foreach (var t in Model)
     {
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.userId)</th>
            <th>@t.id</th>
            <th>@t.title</th>
            <th>@t.completed</th>
        </tr>
     }
         
    </table>
}
```

The controller (ToDoData.cs)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using ToDo.Models;
using System.Net;

namespace ToDo.Controllers
{
    public class ToDoData : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ToDoModel(string searchString)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
            var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookievalue");
                var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
                var _toDoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoStructure>>(json);

            return View(_toDoData);
        }
    }
}
```

(ToDoStrucuture.cs)

```
namespace ToDo.Models
{
    public class ToDoStructure
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public bool completed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to figure it out by myself and found people using _context but I do not know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you play around with the provided link, the API service does provide the data filtering feature.

For example, link: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId=1

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "qui ullam ratione quibusdam voluptatem quia omnis",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "title": "illo expedita consequatur quia in",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "quo adipisci enim quam ut ab",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 9,
    "title": "molestiae perspiciatis ipsa",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 10,
    "title": "illo est ratione doloremque quia maiores aut",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 11,
    "title": "vero rerum temporibus dolor",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 12,
    "title": "ipsa repellendus fugit nisi",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 13,
    "title": "et doloremque nulla",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 14,
    "title": "repellendus sunt dolores architecto voluptatum",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 15,
    "title": "ab voluptatum amet voluptas",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 16,
    "title": "accusamus eos facilis sint et aut voluptatem",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 17,
    "title": "quo laboriosam deleniti aut qui",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 18,
    "title": "dolorum est consequatur ea mollitia in culpa",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 19,
    "title": "molestiae ipsa aut voluptatibus pariatur dolor nihil",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 20,
    "title": "ullam nobis libero sapiente ad optio sint",
    "completed": true
  }
]
```

For filtering the selected userId, you need to provide the query parameter in the url as:

```cs
var json = webClient.DownloadString($"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId={searchString}");


public ActionResult ToDoModel(string searchString)
{
    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookievalue");

    string uri = @"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        uri = uri + $"?userId={searchString}";
    
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(uri);
    var _toDoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoStructure>>(json);

    return View(_toDoData);
}
```

The above URL will lead to a result that the **data filtering is on the server side**.

---

Or you can also perform the **data filtering in the memory** as:

1. By retrieving all the data from the server.
2. Use *System.Linq* `.Where()` to filter data.

```cs
using System.Linq;

public ActionResult ToDoModel(string searchString)
{
    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

    if (!Int32.TryParse(searchString, out int userId)
    {
        // Handle when user provides searchString is not a valid integer.
        // return to view
    }
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookievalue");

    string uri = @"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";

    var json = webClient.DownloadString(uri);
    var _toDoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ToDoStructure>>(json);
    _toDoData = _toDoData.Where(x => x.userId == userId)
        .ToList();

    return View(_toDoData);
}
```